# ora-01036 illegal variable name

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, mybatis

I know there are related questions, but most of the resolutions I have come across on the web have the same solution, **take the semicolon predecessor off your statement in the where clause**. However, this won't work for me because I don't have a semicolon.

I am using MyBatis and running NUnit tests.

MyBatisCode

```
<select id="GetLineNumber" parameterClass="HashTable" resultClass="long">
  <![CDATA[
      SELECT
                     HP.LINE_NUM  
      FROM
                      ODS.HAIL_PLCY_LINE_NUM
      WHERE     
                      PLCY_ID = #PolicyId#
      AND             HCL_ID = #HailCoverageId#
</select>
```

C# Code:
...

```
  Hashtable lineNumberHash = new Hashtable
      {
         {"PolicyId",x.PolicyId}
            ,{"HailCoverageId",x.Id}
                 };
    lastDatabaseCoverage.AddRange(IbatisSqlMapper.QueryForList<T>("GetLineNumber", lineNumberHash));
```

"X" in the above code is an object and the properties PolicyId and Id are valid so please disregard the bit of contextualless information!

Note that I am used to SQL Server so if the Select, From, Where is off then I apologize for the easy fix.

I keep getting the "ORA01036 illegal variable..." message

This is my first question so I don't know how fast they get answered, hopefully fairly quickly though :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message.

Comment: I tried to edit my original post but couldn't (which makes sense). The message is "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" and the title bar says "OracleException was unhandled by user code." The data types for PolicyId and HailCoverageId are both set as numbers (as opposed to strings) in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

PICNIC problem.

The reason the CDATA tag wasn't closed is because I was copy/pasting from my code. What I failed to do was post the entire message. I had some of the code commented out. I didn't think that adding comments was a no-no, but after looking at it again I realized that the CDATA tag is a *literal*.

Taking comments out of the tag (so they aren't being read so literally) fixed the problem. I now have a result mapping issue, but at least I got past this illegal variable nonsense.

Thanks for the help and the wiki article!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you need to close the [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) that you've wrapped the query in. To do that, change this:

```
      AND             HCL_ID = #HailCoverageId#
</select>
```

to this:

```
      AND             HCL_ID = #HailCoverageId#
  ]]>
</select>
```

Comment: I saw that *after* I posted, I'm sorry to confuse you. It *is* indeed closed in the code. I will post back after looking at this again tomorrow.